# Javascript / jQuery post issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, api

I wrote an API that returns data based on a POST request.

When I use an HTML form, it works.  When I use wget with post-data it works, but no matter what javascript code I use, i can't get it to work.

So, I used Chrome Dev Panel, and looking at the networking tab, it shows the py file responding, and it shows the correct response, its just not displaying on the screen.

I thought it was the headers, so my python (API) has this as the headers:

```
print "Content-Type: text/json"
print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
print "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
print "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
print "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">    
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/main.py",
    {
      uname:"username",
      pword:"password"
    },
    function(data,status){
      $(".data").html(data);
      $(".status").html(status);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send</button>
<p>Data: <span class="data"></span></p>
<p>Status: <span class="status"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your browser console is there any error

Comment: "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. "

But that shouldnt affect it

Comment: whether the click handler is getting called? after the button click is there any additional logs in the consle

Comment: Yea, the error above is what happens when I click. Prior to that, nothing is in the log.

Note:  No alert box ever opens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this issue.

I mentioned I used Python to create the API, and when I was sending the data, I just did "print dictobject", the problem is, it needed to be converted to JSON first!

So when javascript got it, it tried to parse the JSON (as was in my headers), and couldn't thus returned nothing.

I discovered the issue by putting dataType: "text" in the ajax call, which disabled javascripts parser.  When the data (finally) printed, I copied the text, and used a json validator to determine it wasn't correct!

The final javascript code:

```
var formData = {uname:"username",pword:"password"};

$.ajax({
    url : "http://be.expressivecomputing.com/cgi-bin/main.py",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        $(".data").html(data);
        $(".status").html(textStatus);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        $(".data").html("FAIL");
        $(".status").html(textStatus);
    }
});
```